# Script for automatic creation of DB tables

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have to make a script which creates schema that must have 1.000 tables, with 1.000 columns. 
Table name (example): TABLE_058
Column name (example): T058_COL_078

Tables should be empty. I'm working with Oracle DB and ain't too apt with SQL/PL-SQL.
Would be much obliged if someone would point me in right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you save it as a script and then execute it under SQL*Plus. The tables are named `TABLE_000` through `TABLE_999` and the columns are similarly sequenced `000` through `999`.

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 2000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SPOOL C:\CreateTables.sql

SELECT
  CASE
     WHEN ColIndex = 0 THEN 'CREATE TABLE TABLE_' || TO_CHAR(TableIndex, 'FM000') || '     ('
     ELSE NULL
     END ||
  '  T' || TO_CHAR(TableIndex, 'FM000') || '_COL_' || TO_CHAR(ColIndex, 'FM000') || '   VARCHAR2(1)' ||
  CASE
     WHEN ColIndex = 999 THEN ');'
     ELSE ','
     END
FROM (
  SELECT TableIndex, ColIndex FROM (
    SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS TableIndex FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000)
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS ColIndex FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000)
  ORDER BY TableIndex, ColIndex);

SPOOL OFF
```

Some things to note:

- The numbering scheme is from 000 through 999 because your template for table/column names uses three digits and the only way to get to 1000 tables/columns like that is to start at zero.
- Change the filename in `SPOOL C:\CreateTables.sql` to a filename that works for you.
- You didn't specify the column type so the script above has them all as `VARCHAR2(1)`
- **It's important to run the above as a script from SQL*Plus**. If you don't, a lot of the SQL*Plus chatter will end up in the spooled output. To run the script from SQL*Plus, just type the "at" sign (`@`) followed by the script's name. If you name it `TableGenScript.sql` then do this:

  ```
  SQL> @TableGenScript.sql
  ```

The first few lines of output from the script look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_000 (  T000_COL_000 VARCHAR2(1),
  T000_COL_001 VARCHAR2(1),
  T000_COL_002 VARCHAR2(1),
  T000_COL_003 VARCHAR2(1),
```

Give it a try and you should be able to tweak this to your specific needs.

---

**Addendum** NikolaB asked how to vary the column type and the answer is too long to fit in a comment...

To vary the column type, take the part of the query that says `|| ' VARCHAR2(1)' ||` and replace it with your data-type logic. For example, if columns 0-599 are `VARCHAR2`, columns 600-899 are `NUMBER`, and columns 900-999 are `DATE`, change the script to something like this:

```
... all the SETs like above, then the SPOOL ...

SELECT
  CASE
     WHEN ColIndex = 0 THEN 'CREATE TABLE TABLE_' || TO_CHAR(TableIndex, 'FM000') || '     ('
     ELSE NULL
     END ||
  '  T' || TO_CHAR(TableIndex, 'FM000') || '_COL_' || TO_CHAR(ColIndex, 'FM000') ||

  CASE -- put the data-type logic in this CASE
    WHEN ColIndex BETWEEN   0 AND 599 THEN '   VARCHAR2(1)'
    WHEN ColIndex BETWEEN 600 AND 899 THEN '   NUMBER'
    ELSE '   DATE'
  END || -- data-type logic ends here and original query resumes

  CASE
     WHEN ColIndex = 999 THEN ');'
     ELSE ','
     END
FROM
... and then the same as above, all the way through to the SPOOL OFF
```

I've highlighted the `CASE` statement with a comment. If you put your data-type logic between the `CASE` and the `END` you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm having difficulty customizing script, do you have some useful link from where i can learn about syntax. I have to have three types of column data(varchar2,date,number) but i can't write it without errors. This makes me feel stupid it sounds so simple.

Comment: @NikolaB - this is far from simple so don't feel dumb. I don't think you'll find any targeted help on the web so I've updated my answer. Check the "Addendum" toward the end for help with varying the data type.

Answer (score 1):

Export the schema's metadata.

```
exp userid=user/pass@db owner=someowner rows=n file=somefile.dmp
```

if you open the file using notepad you could see the DML statements.
you can then import using

```
imp userid=user/pass@otherdb file=somefile.dmp full=y
```

you can also copy to another schema on the same db (usually for testing)

```
imp userid=user/pass@db file=somefile.dmp fromuser=someschema touser=otherschema
```

you can also use the new datapump for parallel and compression enhancements. 
check out [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm)